# Haskell foldr on list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-search-tree

I have a member function in Haskell for a BST. I am trying to use foldr to check if every element in the list is in the BST. My member functions works for single elements and the first line looks like this.

```
member ::(Ord a) =>  BST a -> a -> Bool
```

and when I have:

```
let val = foldr mBST my_list
```

I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> b0 -> b0'
            with actual type `BST Int'
In the first argument of `foldr', namely `mBST'
In the expression: foldr mBST my_list
```

I know foldr has type foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b, so my types are not matching but I don't know how to fix it or if it even possible to use foldr in this situation. But I need to check to see if every element in the list is in my BST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foldr` recieve 3 arguments. A binary function (operator), the accumulator (neutral operand of the operator) and the structure (List).

And you call function could be:

`foldr (&&) true $ map (member mBST) myList`

```
:t member mBST
 member mBST :: (Ord a) => a -> Bool
```

`map` function aplied an unary operator (or a function that recieve one argument) on the elements of the array. After you aplied `member` with `mBST` on every member is on your structure (a list) then check if all are `true` using `foldr`.